# jQuery is it ok to explicitly assign the .queue() length property?

Tags: jquery, queue

I'm new to jQuery, and the first thing I've done is what I imagine is a classic task: to animate a drop-down menu. #navBar is a div containing a ul, and the menu drops down when the user hovers over an li. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#navBar>ul>li").hover(function()
     {
         var $menu = $(this).find("div");
         if ($menu.queue().length > 1) $menu.queue().length = 1;
         $menu.slideDown(200).css("z-index", "1");
     },
     function()
     {
         $(this).find("div").delay(500).slideUp(400).css("z-index","0");
     });
});
```

My question refers to the line:

```
if ($menu.queue().length > 1) $menu.queue().length = 1;
```

I did this to avoid the problem of queuing endless animations, while avoiding the jumpiness of using stop(true, true). This works perfectly, but I feel uneasy about explicitly assigning the length of queue (no other programming language I'm familiar with allows me to do this).

My fear is that by assigning length, I'm just limiting how far down the queue jQuery goes, but not actually deleting queued animations, and potentially causing a memory leak. What I would actually like to do is simply remove any queued animations beyond the first, but can't seem to find a way to do this.

In any case, as I said, it behaves perfectly now. Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something stupid?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what assigning to length would achieve but probably recommend against it. all it's doing is returning the number of items in the array/collection so if it's working in your example I'd imagine it may be popping items off which may cause problems for you later down the track. go with something similar to what Shangkar has below, if you're going to use jQuery you may as well let it do as much of the work as possible - will usually make for cleaner & faster code

Comment: Yes, I would agree, but like I said, so far this has been the only thing that has actually provided the desired behaviour. I'd recommend it, if I could be sure I wasn't breaking something. I've tested it a lot, with no issues, but it would be nice to know that it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently assigning to the length property is fine:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp

If you assign a value to length property of an array which is less than the actual length of the array, the elements after the assigned length are lost.

Good article here:

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-Array-Length-Property.aspx

Comment: That's great news! Well, everybody, if you want to avoid endless animation queues, and don't like how using stop() looks, this solution works wonderfully - depending on how complex your animation is (you might have to change the limit). Thanks very much timothyclifford, those links were just what I needed, but I hadn't thought of simply looking for the answer in javaScript (as opposed to JQuery) sites

Comment: You're welcome. the .length property is just plain old javascript. The jQuery equivalent is .size() however .length is usually preferred due to less overhead. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not possible and what you did is not going to work also. But you can achieve what you want in a different way also. Try this which is basically checking if the element is already animating dont do anything let it complete its animation.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#navBar>ul>li").hover(function()
     {
         var $menu = $(this).find("div");
         if(!$menu.is(":animated")){
             $(this).find("div").slideDown(200).css("z-index", "1");
         }
     },
     function()
     {
         var $menu = $(this).find("div");
         if(!$menu.is(":animated")){
             $(this).find("div").delay(500).slideUp(400).css("z-index","0");
         }
     });
});
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thankyou ShankarSangoli! Unfortunately the solution you suggest can lead to mouseout being ignored, and the menu staying up permanently (or until you hover over then off again). If I take away the "animated" check in the second function, that problem is solved, but then we have long queues of animation again. The thing is, what I wrote does actually work and give me the desired behaviour, but it feels like a hack